# making jquery autocomplete not do anything when a condition is met

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

so I'm using jquery autocomplete and I set the formatItem option to this:

```
formatItem: function(row, i, max) {

    if( some condition to check )
        return '';

    var html = '<process the results from row>';
    return html;
},
```

but doing so will end up having jquery autocomplete display an empty popup since an empty string '' is returned...is there a way to make jquery AC not do anything at all...ie. it will simply stop and not display a popup whatsoever when a condition is met?

returning false still displays a popup and simply just `return;` would end up with a javascript error (the popup won't display alright, but it won't display because of the javascript error instead of because of something legitimate)

Comment: [The plugin you are using](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete) is deprecated. You should be using the [jQueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) instead.

Comment: well I'm using that deprecated one (no choice), so please answer for that plugin